# OpenERP view - one column for field

Tags: xml, view, odoo, multiple-columns

I need to create view that has fields in one group with no labels and other group with fields and labels. So it goes that I need to divide fields groups into three columns - one column for fields with no labels and two columns for group with labels. So it should look something like this:

```
|col1|col2|col3|
field lb   field  
field lb   field
```

But I get this:

```
|col1|col2|col3|col4
field      lb  field  
field      lb  field
```

When I try this:

```
<group colspan="3" col="3">
  <group String="L" colspan="1" col="1">
    <field name="breath_ausc_l_norm" nolabel="1"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_l_wet" nolabel="1"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_l_dry" nolabel="1"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_l_bron" nolabel="1"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_l_weak" nolabel="1"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_l_not" nolabel="1"/>
  </group>
  <group String="R" col="2" colspan="2">
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_norm"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_wet"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_dry"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_bron"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_weak"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_not"/>
  </group>
</group>
```

Comment: which openerp version?

Comment: OpenERP Version - 7.0

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
<group colspan="4" col="4">
  <group String="L" colspan="1">
    <div class="oe_inline">
      <field name="breath_ausc_l_norm" nolabel="1"/>
      <field name="breath_ausc_l_wet" nolabel="1"/>
      <field name="breath_ausc_l_dry" nolabel="1"/>
      <field name="breath_ausc_l_bron" nolabel="1"/>
      <field name="breath_ausc_l_weak" nolabel="1"/>
      <field name="breath_ausc_l_not" nolabel="1"/>
    </div>
  </group>
  <group String="R" colspan="3">
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_norm"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_wet"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_dry"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_bron"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_weak"/>
    <field name="breath_ausc_r_not"/>
  </group>
</group>
```

maybe it's working without the div and class="oe_inline" on every field, too

Comment: It aligns fields horizontally if I try this. Firt groups fields (with no labels) go in one line, not one after another as column.